# Avoiding unused variable warnings with pre-compiler statements inside openmp parallel blocks

Tags: c++, openmp, preprocessor-directive, unused-variables

### Background

My problem arises from a combination of a few particular things.

1. I am using pre-processor statements to determine what kind of calculations to include in the produced executable
2. I am using openmp parallel for blocks with `default(none)` (because I'm paranoid).
3. The code compiles and runs properly, but can spew out unused variable warnings depending on the pre-processor flags. Not technically an error, but I would like to remove those warnings (and no, I don't just mean disabling the compiler warnings, but actually removing the cause i.e. the unused variables).

Essentially, I have something of the form

```
#pragma omp parallel \
  default(none) \
  shared(...) \
  private(...)
  {
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 0; i < num_i; ++i) {

    compute_stuff;

    #if FLAG_1
      compute_more_stuff;
    #endif
    }
  }
```

### Main issue

Suppose for clarity that variable `x` is only required if `FLAG_1` is `true`. I could wrap the declaration for `x` and its usage within `#if FLAG1 ... #endif` statements, but I still need to list `x` within the variable list for the `#pragma omp parallel`, and, as far as I'm aware, I can't nest a `#if FLAG1 ... #endif` within the `#pragma omp parallel` statement (it's several lines long - there are a lot of variables). So, I either I get errors about non-existent variables listing in the pragma omp, or warnings about an unused variable.

### Possible (but unsatisfying) solutions

1. In this case the removed variables are all omp-private, and I acknowledge up front that simply replacing the `default(none)` with `default(private)` would resolve the problem. That said, I do like the coding practice of `default(none)`, and would like to keep it if possible.
2. Another option would be to simply break up the omp-parallel into something like the following, but `compute_stuff` and `compute_more_stuff` have some shared computations / memory access that I'd like the avoid duplicating.

```
#pragma omp parallel \
  default(none) \
  shared(...) \
  private(...)
  {
    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < num_i; ++i) {
      compute_stuff;
    }
  }

#if FLAG_1
#pragma omp parallel \
  default(none) \
  shared(...) \
  private(...)
  {
    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < num_i; ++i) {
      compute_more_stuff;
    }
  }
#endif
```

Any thoughts on how to maintain good coding practices while keep readable and efficient code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C++17, What's about the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute?:

```
#pragma omp parallel \
  default(none) \
  shared(...) \
  private(...)
  [[maybe_unused]] variable_potencially_not_used;
  {
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 0; i < num_i; ++i) {

    compute_stuff;

    #if FLAG_1
      variable_potencially_not_used = 1;
    #endif
    }
  }
```

If not, and alternative is to implement something similat to the [`Q_UNUSED`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_UNUSED) macro. You can declare your own:

````
#define MAYBE_UNUSED(X) (void)X
#pragma omp parallel \
  default(none) \
  shared(...) \
  private(...)
  MAYBE_UNUSED(variable_potencially_not_used);
  {
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 0; i < num_i; ++i) {

    compute_stuff;

    #if FLAG_1
      variable_potencially_not_used = 1;
    #endif
    }
  }```
````

Comment: I didn't know about [[maybe_unused]]. Thank you!